# How do I get my image to automatically fit my Image object in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
            xtype: 'image',
            src: 'http://www.sencha.com/files/blog/old/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/sencha-logo.png',
            left: '50%',
            top: '30%',
            height: '3.515625%',
            width: '13.28125%'
```

The image is cutoff - only a small chunk the size of my Image object appears.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm curious about where did you get this very accurate values for the height and width ?

Comment: what do your left, top, height, width configs mean?

Comment: Basically, what it does is set an absolute position and size on the screen, meaning it is no longer affected by its parent container.  However, if the image in src is too big, it gets cut off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the config "mode: 'image'", this will embed your image in a img tag, respecting your width and height. Or set the background-size in CSS

Edit: also, are you converting a layout in pixels to %? Im currently doing the same thing except in em. Kinda a pain in the a**. Got any useful tips?

Comment: That is absolutely what I am doing...and I feel your pain.  So I tried passing "image" to the mode parameter and my image disappeared altogether...I don't want to know.  What I ended up doing was making a container and setting it as the background, styling the size to be 100% in my sass file.  It works of course, but I want to know how to style the stuff inside the JS objects.  For example, setting the image I passed to src in the Image object to be 100% instead of using this work around.  I've passed some text to buttons and stuff like that, and I want it to resize in the same way.